# SDL2 libs in Debian Wheezy

Tags: debian, sdl, sdl-2

Debian 7.6.0.

I'm try to install SDL2 libraries

aptitude install libsdl2-image-2.0-0 libsdl2-2.0-0

```
but aptitude can't find this packages.
```

My sources.list:

```
deb http://ftp.ru.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main
deb-src http://ftp.ru.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main

deb http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main
```

Online packages.debian.org says that all these packages are in unstable, Is it possible to somehow install these packages without using the unstable branch? (When you try to install the unstable pile appears neudvoletvorennyh dependencies and offers to delete 100+ packages, including gcc)

Comment: Was there something wrong with the [`wheezy-backports` package(s)](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy-backports/libsdl2-dev)?

Comment: Having the same problem here and no, @genpfault's comment does not help at all since libsdl2-IMAGE-2.0-0 is not in the backports either. I guess the only solution is to either install the library yourself OR use Debian Sid. Changing the version is omho a bit of an overkill but on the other hand I've never built libsdl2 or libsdl2-image myself so I don't know what problems one might stumble upon while doing that on Debian Wheezy.